# C# partial class and the get accessor

Tags: c#, partial-classes

basing on the Entity Framework entities, I've created a partial class for one of them. The problem is, I want to add some code before the `ContentValue` is returned. But it does not work -

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ToolTip_Meta))]
public partial class Tooltip
{
    ..some methods etc
}

public class ToolTip_Meta
{
    [Required]
    public string ContentValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ContentValue))
                return this.ContentValue.Replace("\n", "<br/>").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("'", "\\'").Replace("\"", "&quot;");
            return this.ContentValue;
        }
        set { ContentValue = value; }
    }
}
```

when somewhere in my project I want to get the `ContentValue` property value I get the unchanged string, I don't get inside the `get` accessor. How to fix it ?

Comment: Could you create and use a new property that uses `ContentValue` as a backer?

Comment: are you calling get property of ContentValue from within the get property of ContentValue? this should d=not work for sure

Comment: I could, but I want to be sure that everytime the programmer gets the ContentValue property value, he gets the changed string

Comment: Perhaps it would be better te mark the property in the model as internal and wrap a public property (with a slightly) different name around it in the partial class, which would only be satisfactory if it is in a separate assembly.

Comment: Silvermind > the base Tooltip class is auto-generated by the Entity Framework designer, so the only way is to do some tricks with the ContentValue property within the partial class

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this actually has anything to do with partial classes or metadata.  Your problem is actually very simple.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ContentValue))
```

When you access `this.ContentValue`, it calls that getter, which then accesses `this.ContentValue`, which calls the getter...  Thus you're going to either get a StackOverflowException or an OutOfMemoryException.

If you're not experiencing one of those two errors, please update your question to explain *how* it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

In the Entity Framework designer, change the field name of the generated property to `ContentValueInternal`, and mark it as having internal access rather than public.  This can still be mapped to a database field of `ContentValue`.

Then, in your hand-coded partial class, create a new public property called `ContentValue` which has the logic you describe in your question, but which uses the `ContentValueInternal` property internally to store the real value.

Comment: sounds nice, but the problem is that every time the EF model is updated, each programmer must remember to change that property to ContentValueInternal. But someone can forget to do that

Comment: If you are just doing "Update Model From Database" within the designer, it should remember the mappings, so you should not have to reset them all the time.  If you are using source control, and you are storing the edmx with the source, then each programmer should be using the same mappings and thus not need to change it individually.  If for some reason the forgoing does not hold, and it gets reset and someone does forget to change it, then the compiler will complain because you will have a partial class referencing a field that doesn't exist.  So that should be enough of a reminder to fix it.